# EntityCollection<T> ToArray() extension method not working in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, automapper

I'm trying to move my Automapper Entity -> ViewModel map definition from one of my controllers to my MVC app's `OnApplicationStarted()` method.  When I copy it, my Entity's EntityCollection property loses access to its `ToArray()` extension method.  When I try to compile, I get an error telling me that there is no method or extension method that matches its signature.

Code:

```
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        // some Ninject setup code

        Mapper.CreateMap<Game, AdminGameViewModel>()
            .BeforeMap((s, d) =>
            {
                int platCount = s.Platforms.Count;
                var plats = s.Platforms.ToArray(); // <-- line in question
                d.PlatformIDs = new int[platCount];

                for (int i = 0; i < platCount; ++i)
                {
                    d.PlatformIDs[i] = plats[i].ID;
                }
            })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Pros, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Pros.Split(new char[] { '|' })))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Cons, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Cons.Split(new char[] { '|' })))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PlatformIDs, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
```

Again, this code is straight copied and pasted from my controller, where it compiles and runs fine.  I've tried casting to IEnumerable, but that doesn't give me access to the method either.

Comment: Add using for System.Data.Linq

Comment: What is the type of `s.Platforms`?

Comment: @k0stya, you should write your comment as an answer so I can upvote and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following using.

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```